# ERROR GUROBI: List Index out of range

Tags: python, gurobi

My code:

```
import sys
import gurobipy as grb

GRB = grb.GRB

m = grb.Model()

m.Params.timeLimit = 3600

b = m.addVars(10,10,15, vtype=GRB.BINARY)
F = m.addVars(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)

m.addConstrs(F == (b.sum(x,y,z) for x in range(10) for y in range(10) for z in range(15)))

for x in range(10):
    for y in range(10):
        m.addConstrs(sum(b[x][y][z]  for z in range(15)) <= 1 )

for z in range(15):
    for y in range(10):
        m.addConstrs(sum(b[x][y][z]  for x in range(10)) <= 1 )

for x in range(10):
    for z in range(15):
        m.addConstrs(sum(b[x][y][z]  for y in range(10)) <= 1 )

m.setObjective(F, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
m.update()
result = m.optimize()
```

The code is supposed to take 10 teacher, 10 classrooms and 15 hours and return the number of unique schedules that can be found, as such, for every (x,y,z), there is a (x',y',z') with (x != x'), (y != y') and (z != z').

The idea here was a 3D "matrix" with binary numbers. If 1, teacher x is in classroom y at time z, if 0, free.

The problem I'm having is an IndexError: list index out of range. I have x running from 1 to 10, y from 1 to 10, and z from 1 to 15.

I appreciate all help.

edit: just in case, I'm pasting the error here:

```
Changed value of parameter timeLimit to 3600.0
   Prev: 1e+100  Min: 0.0  Max: 1e+100  Default: 1e+100
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exec2.py", line 14, in <module>
    F = m.addVars(vtype=GRB.INTEGER)
  File "model.pxi", line 2261, in gurobipy.Model.addVars (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:73898)
  File "model.pxi", line 198, in gurobipy.__listify.__init__ (../../src/python/gurobipy.c:47440)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

[Model.addConstr()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addconstr.html) takes a linear expression (LinExpr object), while [Model.addConstrs()](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_model_addconstrs.html) takes a Python generator expression.  You should rewrite your constraints as:

```
m.addConstr(F == b.sum('*','*','*'))
m.addConstrs(b.sum(x,y,'*') <= 1 for x in range(10) for y in range(10))
m.addConstrs(b.sum('*',y,z) <= 1 for y in range(10) for z in range(15))
m.addConstrs(b.sum(x,'*',z) <= 1 for x in range(10) for z in range(15))
```